# How to do Task.ContineWith using a Delay before the ContinueWith in C#?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I know I can do a simple Delayed Task like this:

```
Task.Delay(iDelayInMilliseconds).ContinueWith(() => SomeMethod());
```

And I can chain two different methods as sequential tasks like this:

```
Task.Run(() => SomeMethod()).ContinueWith(() => AnotherMethod());
```

What I can't figure out is something like this:

```
Task.Run(() => SomeMethod()).Delay(iDelayInMilliseconds).ContinueWith(() => AnotherMethod());
```

Effectively, I want SomeMethod() to run followed by a delay followed by AnotherMethod().

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In your example it is better to not use old school ContinueWith at all in favour of async/await.  The latter is easier to read

Comment: If you insist on using ContinueWith you can make a delay using `theTask.ContinueWith(t=>Thread.Sleep(iDelayInMilliseconds))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    SomeMethod();
    await Task.Delay(iDelayInMilliseconds);
}).ContinueWith(cw => AnotherMethod());
```

Here, we need to actually *wait* for the inner `Task` (i.e. `Task.Delay(iDelayInMilliseconds)`) to complete, otherwise the `Task` returned by `Task.Run()` will return immediately with it's `Status`  set to `RanToCompletion`.

Of course, if this does not need to run on a `ThreadPool` thread, you can remove `Task.Run()` altogether:

```
// ...
SomeMethod();
await Task.Delay(iDelayInMilliseconds);
AnotherMethod();
```

..which means that you'll have to mark the parent method as `async` and have it return `Task<T>` instead of `T`, or `Task` if it returns `void`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. It's a lot more powerful than Tasks, IMHO, and can be used like a LINQ query, and it interops with tasks and async operations quite easily.

In your case you code can look like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var iDelayInMilliseconds = 4000;

    IObservable<int> query =
        from x in Observable.Start(() => SomeMethod())
        from y in Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(iDelayInMilliseconds))
        from z in Observable.Start(() => AnotherMethod())
        select x + z;

    IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(w => Console.WriteLine(w));
}

public int SomeMethod() => 1;
public int AnotherMethod() => 2;
```

This takes the `4,000` milliseconds and produces `3` on the console.

If you want to stop the query early, you just call `.Dispose()` on the `subscription`.

If some of your methods were `async` and if you wanted a `Task<int>` returned then you can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var iDelayInMilliseconds = 4000;

    IObservable<int> query =
        from x in Observable.StartAsync(() => SomeMethod())
        from y in Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(iDelayInMilliseconds))
        from z in Observable.Start(() => AnotherMethod())
        select x + z;

    Task<int> task = query.ToTask();

    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}

public async Task<int> SomeMethod() => await Task.Run(() => 1);
public int AnotherMethod() => 2;
```

This still produces the correct result with the right delay.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to your code to get it working.